# aarch64 gcc support --fix-cortex-a53-843419

Tags: arm, kernel

I download arm64 arch toolchain from linaro.com

But when i start to build latest kernel with arm64 defconfig

It will show the below error, which means that my arm64 gcc doesn't support --fix-cortex-a53-843419 option.

Is there anyone knows which gcc I can use to fix that problem ?

`linux git:(master) make ARCH=arm64 aarch64-linux-gnu- -j8
arch/arm64/Makefile:23: ld does not support --fix-cortex-a53-843419; kernel may be susceptible to erratum
arch/arm64/Makefile:44: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable`

`linux git:(master) aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/miracle/Misc/gcc-linaro-7.1.1-2017.08-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: '/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/snapshots/gcc.git~linaro-7.1-2017.08/configure' SHELL=/bin/bash --with-mpc=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-mpfr=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libmudflap --enable-lto --enable-shared --without-included-gettext --enable-nls --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-c99 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-long-long --with-cloog=no --with-ppl=no --with-isl=no --disable-multilib --enable-fix-cortex-a53-835769 --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --with-arch=armv8-a --enable-threads=posix --enable-multiarch --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-build-sysroot=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/sysroots/aarch64-linux-gnu --with-sysroot=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc --enable-checking=release --disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/builder_arch/amd64/label/tcwg-x86_64-build/target/aarch64-linux-gnu/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Comment: Sry, just ignore that. I forgot the parameter `CROSS_COMPILE`. So the gcc will use the x86_64 gcc as default.